# Find the distribution of X.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, poisson-distribution

Let X be a random variable that assumes all the non-negative integral values. We
are given that for any positive integer:

$k · \mathbb{P}(X = k) = 10 · \mathbb{P}(X = k − 1)$

Find the
distribution of X.

Can anyone help me with that?

I started it like that:

$\mathbb{P}(X = k) = 10/k \cdot \mathbb{P}(X = k-1) = 10^2/{k\cdot(k-1)}\cdot \mathbb{P}(X=k-2)=...=\frac{10^{(k-1)}}{{k\cdot(k-1)\cdot ... \cdot(k-(k-1))}}\cdot\mathbb{P}(X=0)$

I know the answer should be that $X$~$Poiss(\lambda = 10)$

but I dont know how to turn it into $P(X=k)=\frac{10^k}{k!} \cdot e^{-10}$

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already almost there:  observe that
$$k(k-1)\cdots(k-(k-1)) = k(k-1)(k-2) \cdots (2)(1) = k!.$$  But you also have a small error, since
$$\Pr[X = 1] = \frac{10}{1} \Pr[X = 0], \\ \Pr[X = 2] = \frac{10^2}{2(1)} \Pr[X = 0], \\ \Pr[X = 3] = \frac{10^3}{3(2)(1)} \Pr[X = 0],$$ and so forth.  So your formula should be
$$\Pr[X = k] = \frac{10^k}{k!} \Pr[X = 0],$$ and not $10^{k-1}$ in the numerator.
Now to find $\Pr[X = 0]$, we must have the sum of all probabilities must equal to $1$:
$$1 = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \Pr[X = k] = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{10^k}{k!} \Pr[X = 0] = \Pr[X = 0] \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{10^k}{k!} = \Pr[X = 0] e^{10},$$ where in the last step we have used the series expansion for the function $e^z$:
$$e^z = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{z^k}{k!}.$$
Therefore, $\Pr[X = 0] = e^{-10}$ and the result follows.

Comment: thanks! that's all I needed to understand how to finish.